# Photoshop pt and css px

Tags: css, responsive-design, font-size, photoshop

I am using Photoshop cc (14.2.1). I have a mockup in photoshop which has a font at 14px. I set the font in the browser to be the same, at the same size of 14px, but in the browser the font is smaller. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: 14pt is not equal to 14px . Read [this](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

Comment: did you check that dpi??

Comment: No i am not checking dpi but why ?

Answer (score 14):

**Photoshop method** :

Go to photoshop> edit> preferences > General> Units and Rulers
[or press ctrl + k then select units and rulers]

Change Units as per your wish.
select : Rulers as Pixel.
         Type as pixel.

This will give you font sizes in pixel.

**Alternate method :** 
Use this conversion table to convert your unit to pixels
http://reeddesign.co.uk/test/points-pixels.html

or use this link

http://www.endmemo.com/sconvert/pixelpoint.php

Comment: i already select Rulers as Pixel but font-size never change. 14pt font-size show 14px .But the browser the font is smaller.

Comment: select both ruler and type as pixels. Type is more important.